# Hive 1.1.0 on zLinux RHEL6 using IBM JDK 1.7.1

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, hive

I've beeen working on porting over Hive 1.1.0 to zLinux with RHEL6, using the IBM JDKs. As you can imagine this has caused a number of issues. First RHEL6 doesn't at the moment have a way of getting Snappy Java to install due to the dependency on `libstdc++-static`. There are number of guides out there that enable you to get 1.1.3 on the system by installing it on RHEL7 and coping the JAR over, I took mine from here:
[linux-on-ibm-z/docs - Snappy Java](https://github.com/linux-on-ibm-z/docs/wiki/Snappy-Java)

I've also hit another interesting issue with a the Hive Query Language park of the set-up, namely it was failing here, with the following issue:

```
[INFO] Hive Common ....................................... SUCCESS [4.026s]
[INFO] Hive Serde ........................................ SUCCESS [4.401s]
[INFO] Hive Metastore .................................... SUCCESS [16.867s]
[INFO] Hive Ant Utilities ................................ SUCCESS [0.607s]
[INFO] Spark Remote Client ............................... SUCCESS [3.787s]
[INFO] Hive Query Language ............................... FAILURE [16.621s]
[INFO] Hive Service ...................................... SKIPPED

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project hive-exec: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/test/work/hive/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/debug/Utils.java:[36,27] cannot find symbol
import com.sun.management.HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean;
private static final String HOTSPOT_BEAN_NAME = "com.sun.management:type=HotSpotDiagnostic";
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get around the issues by applying the differences mentioned in the following patch -
https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12696113/HIVE-9545.1.patch.txt